How to generate F statistics for permutation for two-way ANOVA using avop in lmPerm package
I am running permutation for two-way ANOVA using aovp in the lmPerm package in R. I can generate the ANOVA table with df, Sum Sq, R Mean Sq, Inter. and P values but not the corresponding F statistics. Is it possible to generate such F statistics with avop for my main effects and the interaction?
I'm new to R, so not sure how to provide my data, but this it the code I am using once I load my CSV data file into R:
install.packages(“lmPerm”)
library(lmPerm)
set.seed(1234)
my_data$Treatment <- as.factor(my_data$Treatment)
fit <- aovp(Stage ~ Treatment*Measure_Temp, data=my_data, perm="Prob")
summary(fit)

I have used the following to try and get at what I want, but am not sure what I'm doing!
str(fit)
I see that it is possible to generate an F statistics for lmp, but not sure how to do it for avop.
I have tried
summaryC(fit) but get the following error I do not understand:
Error in object[[i]]$coefficients :
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
My data are just in a table with each factor in a column and the response in a column.
Thanks in advance for any help!
